# How does Apple Calendar get Facebook friends' birthdays after Graph API v2.0?

Tags: ios, facebook, macos, facebook-graph-api

Facebook has restricted access to user's friends from Graph API 2.0. But, I still see certain apps that are able to get friends' data.

For example, Apple still syncs Facebook friends' birthday with their Calendar (Not all contacts though).

I suspected these contacts might also be using Apple products and hence are visible because of that. But, some of the contacts, who don't own any Apple products, also showed up through Facebook birthdays.

How are they doing this? Is there a separate API for accessing such data?

Comment: Whoever down-voted, may I ask why?

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate API. Some companies may have a special deal with Facebook (one you will obviously never get), but friends data is restricted to those friends who authorized your App.